# SQL server virtual memory usage and performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization

I have  a very large DB used mostly for analytics. The performance overall is very sluggish. I just noticed that when running the query below, the amount of virtual memory used greatly exceeds the amount of physical memory available. Currently, physical memory is 10GB (10238k bytes) whereas the virtual memory returns significantly more - 8388607k bytes. That seems really wrong, but I'm at a bit of a loss on how to proceed.

```
USE [master];
GO
select 
    cpu_count
,    hyperthread_ratio
,    physical_memory_in_bytes / 1048576 as 'mem_MB'
,    virtual_memory_in_bytes / 1048576 as 'virtual_mem_MB'
,    max_workers_count
,    os_error_mode
,    os_priority_class
from 
    sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

Comment: 10 GB is around 10,000,000,000 bytes not 10238 bytes

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking ? Not sure what the question is.

Comment: **Note:** I edited the question to change 'bytes' to 'k bytes'. Not absolutely sure this is what was meant.

Answer (score 2):

Are you having general problems on this box or problems with a specific query?  In most cases, query optimization is best asked here, but everything else about general SQL Server performance profiles belongs on serverfault.com, especially OS/Server/hardware configuration.

Comment: Yes, I meant MB. There isn't a specific query to optimize, the discrepency between physical and virtual seems way out of wack. More of a generic question. I suppose this question is better asked at serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

> I have a very large DB used mostly for analytics.

OLAP: Memory and CPU intensive.

> Currently, physical memory is 10GB

Small server: Does not compute.

> That seems really wrong, but I'm at a bit of a loss on how to proceed

Upgrade server. A Very large dDatabase is 100+Gigabyte - likely these days 1000+ Gigabyte. 10Gb RAM for that uner analytical circumstance: joke, not server.